# Image delete with checkbox in list-view

Tags: django, django-admin

When I delete record with an image I use this method

```
def delete(self, using=None):
    try:
        obj = Photo.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
        obj.image.delete()
    except:
        pass
    super(Photo, self).delete()
```

How would I delete many records with checkbox. When I delete many records through the admin list-view, associated images aren't deleted.

Answer (score 0):

There is a warning about three paragraphs down from [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#admin-actions).  That's exactly what you need to know.  This performs a bulk-delete, which doesn't call your model delete.